# Is there any keyboard shortcut to switch JavaScript on/off in Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut to switch JavaScript on/off in Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/keyboard%20shortcuts), there isn't.

Comment: Can we make custom ?

Comment: No @MetalGear the linked article mentions it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options:

1. If you use the [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) add-on, it uses ctrl-shift-backslash as the keyboard shortcut to toggle JS permissions for the main domain of the page.  This is an imperfect solution, however, since many sites use JS from multiple domains.
2. If you want something simpler, the [JS Switch](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/js-switch/) add-on gives you a toolbar button to do a full toggle of JS, but it doesn't appear to have a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I use web developer toolbar which is also having the toogle button like JS Switch