# Shortcut for disabling JavaScript in Firefox 8

Tags: firefox, shortcuts, javascript

I have found [this site](http://www.dxdo.com/firefox-8-shortcuts-new-firefox-7-shortcuts/) with Firefox shortcuts. They mention a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> but it doesn't work for me.

I need shortcut for quick switching to without JavaScript mode during debugging of my site.

Can anybody help?

EDIT: I need to stop executing JavaScript on the currently opened page. Previous changes on the page made by JavaScript will stay preserved.

Comment: You can install the [Preferences Toolbar](http://prefbar.tuxfamily.org/) add-on and that gives you a JavaScript checkbox.

Comment: would a plugin like [QuickJava](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickjava/) suffice

Comment: [noscript](http://noscript.net/features#basics) seems to have ctrl+shift+\ to temporarily disable

Comment: Preferences Toolbar and Quick Java disables javascript after reloading page, not immadiately. Maybe I should emphasize it in problem description. Noscript disables all previous changes made by javascript. so no one solution is suitable for me. I resolved it only programatically, I created HTML element on my site, I attached  an onclick event to it and in this event is run comman "debugger();". This command pauses executing javascript on my site. But some shortcut to stop javascript would be better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any keyboard shortcut to switch JavaScript on/off in Firefox?](http://superuser.com/questions/249189/is-there-any-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-javascript-on-off-in-firefox)

Comment: @CiroSantilli: The proposed duplicate is nearly 5 yrs old.  Do you know if it is still correct?

Comment: @fixer1234 this is also about the same age. What matters the most is concentrating info: old questions can get new answers. We can close either way. Rather close this way as that one has more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

install the [keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) extension, then add a key with this code:

```
var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(
   Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
prefs.setBoolPref("javascript.enabled", !prefs.getBoolPref("javascript.enabled"));
```

this toggles firefox's "javascript enabled" preference. i've tested it on firefox 9 on ubuntu lucid, and it works.

more keyconfig examples: http://snarfed.org/firefox_keyconfig_extension

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613524/toggle-javascript-support-programmatically-without-restarting-firefox

Comment: you can now do `Services.prefs.setBoolPref` http://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Opera browser is unbeaten here too.

In Opera, you just press two keys, sequentially: `F12`, `j` to toggle JavaScript disabled/enabled state on the current tab. Scripts are stopped immediately, you'll only need to reload page to start scripts again.

BTW, the last "true" Opera is Opera version 10.10. YMMV with newer Opera.